# Tag synonym drupal-5.x to drupal-5

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently for the specified Drupal tags we use:

- For Drupal 7: `drupal-7`
- For Drupal 6: `drupal-6`
- For Drupal 5: `drupal-5` and `drupal-5.x`

Can we get the two Drupal tags merged, into drupal-5. `drupal-5.x` currently hold more questions than `drupal-5` and I really would like to avoid manually retagging them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the amount of tags was limited along with the response, I decided to retag the questions myself.